# Trying to hide button based on user email

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have this button:

```
<a id="customAddNew" href="/ibs/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId={CED7A37E-B1B4-46DD-B5C6-9232195D7E16}&amp;RootFolder=" target="_self">Submit Work Order​​​</a>
```

I'm trying to use this script to hide the button based on the user logged in:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    var email = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "EMail",
        debug: false
        });

    var trimmedEmail = email.split("@");    
    var newButton = document.getElementById("customAddNew");

    if (trimmedEmail[1] == "napacanada.com"){
        //Is NAPA User, which can't Add New Items
        alert("napa user");
        newButton.style.display = "none";
        //$('#customAddNew').attr("display","none");
        alert("check point")
    }else{
        //Is City User, can Add New Items
        alert("none napa user");
        newButton.style.display = "block";  
        //$('#customAddNew').attr("display","block");
    }
</script>
```

I've tried doing it using JavaScript and jQuery but neither worked. This is the error I get:

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

The first alert runs fine depending on the user, just not the check point alert

Comment: jquery: display is a css property

Comment: You may be running that code before the element was added to the DOM. And just a note: whatever this button does, you should also check the user permissions on the server-side, or your app/site will be very easy to hack.

Comment: It's a private intranet, users who don't have access will get an access denied if they click on the button. But I'd rather they don't see the button at all if they don't have access.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make sure the button renders before the JavaScript?

Comment: Put the javascript after the button in the markup – I recommend you put it right before `</body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this script isn't set to run at any particular time, which means it could execute before your button appears on the page. You're using jQuery, so you can take advantage of the document.ready event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var email = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "EMail",
        debug: false
        });

    var trimmedEmail = email.split("@");    
    var newButton = document.getElementById("customAddNew");

    if (trimmedEmail[1] == "napacanada.com"){
        //Is NAPA User, which can't Add New Items
        alert("napa user");
        newButton.style.display = "none";
        //$('#customAddNew').attr("display","none");
        alert("check point")
    }else{
        //Is City User, can Add New Items
        alert("none napa user");
        newButton.style.display = "block";  
        //$('#customAddNew').attr("display","block");
    }
    });

</script>
```

For more info: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Glad to help! It sounds like this is the answer you were looking for, in which case could you please mark it as the selected answer (click the checkmark)?

Comment: I tried earlier but it said I needed to wait 6 minutes. Also, is there something wrong with the way I'm setting the display with the jquery lines. I've tried using them instead of the javascript ones but it won't work.

Comment: @Batman It should be `$('#customAddNew').css("display","block");`